# RxJava Live Reactive Queue (with on off switch)

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-android, reactive

Working on an android app in kotlin.

I need to set up a system to be able to do work from a live queue (and observe the results of the work in a stream).

But I also have to be able to toggle the "queue processing" depending on a couple external factors (which also come in as streams) like `networkIsAvailable (Observable<Boolean>)`.

I can't use `Observable.fromIterable()` because that creates the iterable right away and this queue will adjust and items may get removed.

I need some kind of loop where I can finish the item, check to make sure we should keep going, and then pop the first item of the queue and do that.

I'm not sure how to do some kind of loop like this in a subscription?

The queue can also become empty and things should start again when the toggle is turned back on.

Perhaps I should push out that determination (about whether to process the next item in the queue or not) into a `Subject<Boolean>?` and then have a subscription to that subject that starts the process again?

examples:

turn on ---- process top of queue, process top of queue (previous was polled off the queue) --- turn off -- no more processing

turn back on -- process top of queue, queue-empty -- stops

add item to queue -- processes -- stops queue empty

turn on processing -- add item to queue-- doesnt process until its turned back on

turn on -- processing top item

Comment: could you give more information? I don't understand your intention since English is not my strength.

Comment: Sorry. What would you like to know? Non-technical requirements:

Have a queue of things to process
Be able to listen to the result of the queue items being processed and do stuff with them

Be able to turn on and off the processing asynchronously

Comment: Sadly, I can't helped you. :)

Comment: I just added some more concrete examples.

Comment: what's you want is switch `on/off` feature?

Comment: Yes. Backed with a live queue which may have items removed, reordered. Also may run out of items and then be refilled.

Comment: Hey, it seems to  [PublishSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/PublishSubject.html) is for you, but you need to wrap it to support `on/off` feature.

Comment: You are looking for [`valve()`](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce that looks like what I need. I've seen you on the androiddev subreddit before :). Thanks!

Comment: @EpicPandaForce will you add `valve` as an answer below so I can mark it as correct and give you the karma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `valve()` operator from [RxJava2Extensions](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions) for this.

```
public PublishProcessor<Boolean> flowControl = PublishProcessor.create();

public void start() {
    Flowable./*...*/
            .compose(FlowableTransformers.valve(flowControl))
            .subscribe(/*...*/);
```

In which case `flowControl.onNext(true)` will start the stream, and `flowControl.onNext(false)` will stop and queue it.

(Any other Rx2 type must be converted to Flowable to use it.)

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this issue recently (listening for pressure when managing NIO selection keys) and converged upon a relatively simple solution which uses common operators:

```java
Queue<T> queue;

// This controls whether the queue is being polled or not.
// It's probably a good idea to make sure this emits the last value upon
// subscription using a BehaviorProcessor or a ReplayFlowable etc.
Flowable<Boolean> condition;

// This is a "dumb" generator which continuously polls the queue and emits items
Flowable<T> generator = Flowable.generate(emitter -> {
    T item = queue.poll();
    if (item != null) {
        emitter.onNext(item);
    }
});

// We wire our generator and condition together to achieve the expected result.
Flowable<T> drainWhileCondition = condition.distinctUntilChanged()
    .concatMap(c -> c
        ? generator.takeUntil(condition.filter(Boolean.FALSE::equals))
        : Flowable.empty());
```

---

You can also make a transformer method for this:

```java
static <T> FlowableTransformer<T, T> valve(Flowable<Boolean> condition) {
    return upstream -> condition.distinctUntilChanged()
            .concatMap(c -> c
                    ? upstream.takeUntil(condition.filter(Boolean.FALSE::equals))
                    : Flowable.empty());
}
```

And use it like so:

```java
Flowable<T> generator;
Flowable<Boolean> condition;

Flowable<T> valvedGenerator = generator.compose(valve(condition));
```